# Chrome Rails Session's Cookie Change Random Times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome

I'm on Rails 3.2.22.5 for one of my apps. After the Chrome v80 update, started to experience sessions expiring way before the default expire. So after doing inspect watching, I noticed the cookie id assigned for the session_store changes randomly.

I noticed these values for the session:

```
HttpOnly: true
Secure: null
SameSite:  null
```

Would these be related to my issue?

Comment: It would help if you add info like, what session store are using? What's the default session expire time? What's the cookie expire time? Is this happening for some sessions on Chrome 80 or all?

Answer (score 0):

Looks Like you have a Dynamic Session, which is there to protect you.

> dynamic

- Harder to guess ( but that shouldnt be a problem )
- Automatically invalidates all sessions when the server restarts ( might be useful if you use local caches)

> static

- Sessions stay readable forever
- Multiple servers possible without syncing the keys

---

Relevant section from [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#secret):

> This is the secret used to sign the session ID cookie. This can be either a string for a single secret, or an array of multiple secrets.
>
> If an array of secrets is provided, only the first element will be used to sign the session ID cookie, while all the elements will be considered when verifying the signature in requests.

---

I would honestly just clear your cookies like in this tutorial and see if that helps you: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647